# Can't get namspaced element

Tags: javascript, xml-namespaces, domparser

I have a string with a namespaced XML document:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:zapi="http://zotero.org/ns/api">
    <entry>
      <zapi:year>2014</zapi:year>
    </entry>
  </feed>
```

I parse this with a javascript DOM parser (where zXml is the string above):

```
var dp = new DOMParser();
var zDom = dp.parseFromString(zXml, "text/html");
var entry = zDom.querySelector("entry");
```

Then I want the year so I try:

```
entry.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://zotero.org/ns/api", "year")
```

Unfortunately this gives me an empty list, `[]`.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it. Just use

```
var zDom = dp.parseFromString(zXml, "text/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

How opposed to jQuery are you?
http://jsbin.com/vutura/3/edit

```
zXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:zapi="http://zotero.org/ns/api"><entry><zapi:year>2014</zapi:year></entry></feed>';
;

zDom = $.parseXML(zXml);
console.log($(zDom).find('entry').text());
```

Comment: ;-) -- It is for simple pages that should load fast so I do not use jQuery there.

Comment: Ya I upvoted your answer, since it was just a mistype.

Comment: More a copy+paste. ;-) -- Though I was not aware of the difference. Or I have forgotten it.